# Java(LibGdx) java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, libgdx

```
public class Tube {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Texture t01;
    private Tube[] tubes;  //<----------------
    private Random r;

    public Tube(){
        r= new Random();
        x = 400 ; y = 0;
        t01 = new Texture("tube.png");
        tubes = new Tube[3];   //<------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i<tubes.length;i++){
            tubes[i] = new Tube();
            tubes[i].x = r.nextInt(10);
            tubes[i].y = r.nextInt(10);
        }
    }

    public void drawTube(SpriteBatch batch){
        for (int i = 0; i<tubes.length;i++) {
            batch.draw(t01, tubes[i].x, tubes[i].y);
        }
    }
```

Правельно ли я понимают, что нельзя создавать массив обьекта Tube[] в этом же классе Tube. Если да, то почему? Как по другому реализовать это?

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.InputStream.<init>(InputStream.java:45)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:123)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:146)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще можно, есть даже паттерн проектирования "Компоновщик" который основан на этом.
Вам нужно добавлять элементы динамически когда это нужно, а не при создании нового экземпляра. Иначе у вас при создании экземпляра создается еще 3 таких, в которых тоже самое еще раз три по три, 3*3*3*3*3... в итоге бесконечность.
Нужно ограничить создание новых экземпляров, либо добавлять их вне конструкторов

Comment: Не мог бы ты написать код ограничения?

Comment: Ну.. это полностью зависит от того что ты хочешь реализовать
Как минимум делать какой то флажок, является ли объект дочерним для какого то другого, если да то не создавать новые объекты, если нет то создать. Но это все уже костыли.

Comment: Массив класса Tube[] - три трубы. потом в методе draw их отрисовать.

Comment: Дело в том что каждая труба ВСЕГДА содержит в себе 3 трубы, которые в свою очередь содержат еще по 3 трубы, ...суть я надеюсь понятна? Либо использовать другой класс для хранения трех труб, либо одной трубе давать 3 трубы НЕ в конструкторе, а к примеру прописать отдельный метод для этого

Comment: я создал функцию initTube()  и проинициализировал массив